# Setting on li width of it's children a

Tags: jquery

I want to set each `li` width of it's own `a`. Here it is [the code](http://jsbin.com/aduruk/3/edit) I'm trying with:

```
if($('ul').length()) { 
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).children('a').each(function() {
            var width2 = $(this).style.width();
            $('ul li').style.width = width2;
            $(this).text(width2);
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="about-me"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="portfolio"><a href="#">Realizations</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have added a background-color css to your "a" elements. Look what happend http://jsbin.com/utesiz/1/edit

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, a and li has different widths just for the test. I want jQuery to set width of each li of it's children a. For example: if second href has width of 118px I want that its parent li has the same added inline in html.

Comment: Can you rewrite your question and make it clearer?  It will help others answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var width;
$('ul li a').each(function() {
  width = $(this).css('width');
  $(this).parent('li').css('width', width);
});
```

it selects all `a` elements, gets width and sets to parent `li` element

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [updated jsBin](http://jsbin.com/aduruk/6/edit).

In jQuery, you can access style attributes with `.css("attribute")`, and update with `.css("attribute","value")`.  Also, you can just say `$("ul").length`, no need for `()`.

Final result:

```
if($('ul').length) { 
   $('ul li').each(function() {
      $(this).children('a').each(function() {
         var width2 = $(this).css("width");
         $('ul li').css("width",width2);

      });
   });
 }
```